# Unit testing in ant project

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am currently trying to introduce unit tests to a legacy project based on ant. The problem is that the project's structure is a little unconventional: Java files mixed up  with xml files in the same directory, there are multiple java source directories, the Java files depend on import jars wich are not present in the same project ...

What is a  clean way to introduce unit tests to a project with this structure:

```
--->project
     ----->folder1
     ----->folder2
           -----file1.java
           -----file2.xml
           -----file3.prop
     ----->folder3
```

Comment: A unit test always has the same package structure as the class it's testing.  I'm not sure how it would differ for this project.  You can place the unit tests in the same directories, and set-up your ant script to conditionally compile them.  Or you can mirror the directory structure under a unitTests directory within the root project path, and only compile that structure if you want tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it like:

```
--->project
     ----->folder1
     ----->folder1-test
     ----->folder2
           -----file1.java
           -----file2.xml
           -----file3.prop
     ----->folder2-test
           -----file1Test.java
           -----file2Test.xml
     ----->folder3
     ----->folder3-test
```

Or bite the bullet and refactor using maven conventions

```
folder1/src/main/java
folder1/src/main/resources
folder1/src/test/java
folder1/src/test/resources
etc...
```